# Compile error while trying to increment iterator returned by initializer_list.begin()

Tags: c++, c++11

If the code below is compiled, an error message is produced by clang 4 ([live on ideone](https://ideone.com/H155T4))

> error: expression is not assignable (this one -> ++(init.begin()))

and by GCC 6.3 ([live on ideone](https://ideone.com/YUVp2D))

> error: lvalue required as increment operand (this one -> ++(init.begin()))

The return value of `initializer_list<T>.begin()` is `const T*`, which should be perfectly incrementable. What am I missing here? I am not asking how to make the code work since it is straightforward. What I would like to know why my code is ill-formed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    initializer_list<int> init { 1, 2, 3 };
    // omit the first element and do whatever
    for_each(++(init.begin()), init.end(), [](const auto & number){ /* whatever */ });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, ++(init.begin()) should increment whatever is returned by begin() by one.

Comment: `init.begin() + 1` should do exactly what you want: https://ideone.com/AAG838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the expression of a function call with non reference return type is an rvalue
2) rvalues referring to object of primitive type are never modifiable
( in other words, you cannot modify a temporary of primitive type )

note that if you used, say, std::vector instead of initializer_list the result would have been compiler dependent ( because vector::iterator can be a class, and you *can* call a non const member of an rvalue of class type ).

finally, we have std::next() to expressively get the past-one iterator; this has also the bonus of working with any iterator category.

Comment: Thanks, man! Completely forgot about this little inconvenience - rvalues referring to object of primitive type are never modifiable.

Comment: Right, `std::next()` is what I use to overcome the issue. The question was a result of my curiosity.